# How to find the derivative with respect to the transformed co-ordinates.

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

I am stuck with something very simple , would be glad to get help . 
Suppose if i have a transformation matrix J , how do i find the derivative with respect to new co-ordinates , and derivative of function with respect to the transformed co-ordinates. 
For example i have a transformation

[image]

My interest is to find $dx_i'$ and $\frac{\partial f'}{\partial x_i'}$

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbf{X}'=\mathbf{JX}\Rightarrow x'=x\cosh\theta+y\sinh\theta\Rightarrow dx'=\cosh\theta dx+\sinh\theta dy$

$\frac{\partial f'}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial y'}=\frac{f_{x}}{\sinh\theta}+\frac{f_{y}}{\cosh\theta}$

the same for $y$.

Comment: Can you tell me what $dx'$ means here  and how you find it \?

Comment: $dx_1=dx$ and $dx_2=dy$ and $(\sinh\theta)'=\cosh\theta$ , $dx'$ is the change of x in the new coordinates (prime in all those equations is denoting "new coordinates" not derivative)

Comment: Why have you got $dx'=sinh\theta dx + ycosh\theta dy$ ?? something that don't understand :(

Comment: Oh please accept my apologies, I was in harry yesterday, I corrected it, sorry again.